# Como acomodar en inorder, posorder, preorder

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

tengo un problema en el orden de arboles binarios no me queda el orden de cada uno
este es mi código espero puedan ayudarme soy nuevo con esto de los arboles binarios:

```
//Inorder
public void inorder(Nodo n){
    if(n!=null){
        inorder(n.izquierda);
        System.out.println("indice "+n.llave+" nombre "+n.nombre+" Edad "+n.edad+" Sexo "+n.sexo);
        inorder(n.derecha);
    }
}
 public void preorden(Nodo n){
    if(n!=null){
        System.out.println("indice "+n.llave+" nombre "+n.nombre+" Edad "+n.edad+" Sexo "+n.sexo);
        preorden(n.izquierda);
        preorden(n.derecha);
    }
}
public void postorden(Nodo n){
    if (n != null) {
        postorden(n.izquierda);
         postorden(n.derecha);
         System.out.println("indice "+n.llave+" nombre "+n.nombre+" Edad "+n.edad+" Sexo "+n.sexo);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hola. No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, ¿tienes dudas sobre qué hace cada método o, no entiendes el código que tienes para resolver los tipos de recorridos que has indicado?

Comment: Tengo la duda de como hacer las posiciones del árbol binario que es inorder, posorder y preorder. En el código que hice no esta haciendo bien el recorrido de para las posiciones.

Answer (score 0):

me he basado en lo que has comentado para ponerte a modo de código cómo lo he hecho yo siempre en Java. No es para copiar-pegar, pues uso clases que no tendrás, pero quédate con la idea de qué hace cada método, y cómo resuelve el árbol binario de entrada según qué tipo de ordenamiento se elija:

Árbol para el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí el código usado. A diferencia de ti, no le paso un "nodo", sino un árbol binario, y dependiendo de qué tipo de método llame, así lo ordena según con qué política: PostOrder, PreOrder, Inorder.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree<Integer> arbol = BinaryTree.binary(10,
                BinaryTree.binary(20, BinaryTree.leaf(40), BinaryTree.leaf(50)), BinaryTree.leaf(30));
        System.out.println("\nArbol: \n" + TreeUtils.toPrettyBinaryTree(arbol));
        System.out.println("Recorrido preOrder: " + preOrder(arbol));
        System.out.println("Recorrido postOrder: " + postOrder(arbol));
        System.out.println("Recorrido inorder: " + inorder(arbol));

    }

    public static <E> List<E> preOrder(BinaryTree<E> t) {
        List<E> res = null;

        switch (t.getType()) {
        case Empty:
            res = Lists2.empty();
            break;
        case Leaf:
            res = Lists2.ofElements(t.getLabel());
            break;
        case Binary:
            res = Lists2.ofElements(t.getLabel());
            res.addAll(preOrder(t.getLeft()));
            res.addAll(preOrder(t.getRight()));
            break;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static <E> List<E> postOrder(BinaryTree<E> t) {
        List<E> res = null;

        switch (t.getType()) {
        case Empty:
            res = Lists2.empty();
            break;
        case Leaf:
            res = Lists2.ofElements(t.getLabel());
            break;
        case Binary:
            res = postOrder(t.getLeft());
            res.addAll(postOrder(t.getRight()));
            res.add(t.getLabel());
            break;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static <E> List<E> inorder(BinaryTree<E> t) {
        List<E> res = null;
        switch (t.getType()) {
        case Empty:
            res = Lists2.empty();
            break;
        case Leaf:
            res = Lists2.ofElements(t.getLabel());
            break;
        case Binary:
            res = Lists2.ofCollection(inorder(t.getLeft()));
            res.add(t.getLabel());
            res.addAll(inorder(t.getRight()));
            break;

        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comentando un poco por encima, la clase "Lists2" es una manera más cómoda de implementar las clásicas "listas" en java, que de tal manera no servirían en mi código (`new ArrayList<E>()`). Las funciones de `empty()` crean una lista vacía, mientras que `ofElements()` y `ofCollection()` soportan varios elementos, o para la última, una colección de los mismos.

Después, para la clase que me implementa un `BinaryTree<E>`, hay algunas cosas interesantes, como el enumerado por el tipo de árbol que se trate. Así, si es binario, hoja o vacío, entra en algún caso específico del `switch`.

Si te fijas, los métodos se realizan de manera recursiva a la hora de recorrer el árbol y ordenar la salida.

La salida por consola es:

```java
Arbol: 
*10
   +20
      +40)
      +50)
   +30)

Recorrido preOrder: [10, 20, 40, 50, 30]
Recorrido postOrder: [40, 50, 20, 30, 10]
Recorrido inorder: [40, 20, 50, 10, 30]
```

A modo de conclusión final puedes apreciar para qué sirve cada método:

Con preorder colocamos primero el root, el padre izquierdo con sus hijos ordenados de izquierda a derecha, y el padre derecho.

Con postorder empezamos de abajo a arriba. Arrancamos de los hijos de izquierda a derecha, subimos a los padres de igual forma, y terminamos con el root.

Finalmente, para el recorrido en inorder, se coge el hijo izquierdo, luego su padre, luego el hijo derecho. Subimos de nivel siguiendo la misma filosofía.

Por último, dejo claro que el código lo he sacado de un repositorio, no es mío al 100%, sólo lo he acoplado a tu pregunta.